# How do you descale a dishwasher heating element?

Tags: appliances, maintenance

I've tried something I got at Lowes (with the wax plug, you put upside down) and CLR.

The CLR worked the best, but didn't really get it off and it's building up again.

I've heard vinegar will work if you use it regularly.

Comment: This question is about appliance repair, not home improvement.  Voting to close.

Comment: @Niall: This would apply to home improvement as well

Answer (score 1):

Might want to check out [this thread](http://www.fixya.com/support/t941503-gritty_white_film_all_over_dishwasher).  Seems like they have a few different ideas:

1. CLR (which you already tried)
2. Run vinegar through the dishwasher.
3. Use a different detergent (can vouch for cascade complete here - it's awesome)
4. Use a [special filter/water softener](http://www.dishwasherfilter.com/).